# Marlin as default file manager in Gnome 3.2 (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: 11.10, gnome, default, filemanager, marlin

Im marlin preferences I click on "Make my default file manager", but nothing changed. All apps like Chrome or Skype still open Nautilus like default. Thanx for any help.

Comment: Ubuntu does not use Gnome 3.2 by default. Did you add a PPA? Otherwise, you should edit the question to say 3.0.

Comment: Yes, I install it from PPA

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked of the Marlin maintainer on Ubuntu Launchpad at the end of May 2011. This is the link to the answer that was marked as solved.

[How to set Marlin as the default file manager](https://answers.launchpad.net/marlin/+question/159780)

Notice this answer given by the maintainer on the first of June 2011:

> Hello, to make marlin default filemanager just click on a folder in
>   nautilus "open with" and select marlin and check default application.
>   However nautilus on gnome draw the desktop too, marlin doesn't, u can
>   disable nautilus desktop via gconf or u can remove the filemanager
>   flag in the session files (if u re using unity) or in gconf on other
>   systems.
>
> Anyway it's a bit earlier to make marlin a default application, it's
>   not released yet, we'll find an automated way to make it default when
>   the time come.
>
> Happy testing.

A similar question was asked again on 10th December 2011 and also marked as solved. Here is the link.

[Another Launchpad question about making Marlin the default file manager](https://answers.launchpad.net/marlin/+question/181468)

So, you are using an application that is still being developed and is perhaps fit for testing but not yet ready for being a Nautilus replacement. It may work fine as a simple file manager but Nautilus does more than browse files and folders. This is why Nautilus stills opens when you perform the actions that you describe.

It also seems that Marlin is more suited to the Xfce desktop environment than the Gnome environment whether Gnome 2 or Gnome 3

Here is a link to the exo-utils package mentioned in the other links. Notice this description:

> This package contains the Xfce settings plugin and the utility files
>   for ....

[Launchpad link to exo-utils Oneiric package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/exo-utils)

The only other thing I can add is that you will find the exo-utils package in the Ubuntu software Centre but notice that it is listed as being an Xfce settings plugin. You are not using Xfce. Is this the cause of your problem and the answer?

Regards and happy testing

Comment: Thanx for detailed response, really helpful